# Area of triangle using 3 sets of coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, area

I am doing one question where i need to find area of triangle with given 3 sets of coordinates

So what will be the logic to convert array to pair in (a1,b1) (a2,b2) (a3,b3) and how to find area of triangle using this vertices

Here is my code

```
def getTriangleArea(x, y):

///What will be the code 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    x_count = int(input().strip())

    x = []

    for _ in range(x_count):
        x_item = int(input().strip())
        x.append(x_item)

    y_count = int(input().strip())

    y = []

    for _ in range(y_count):
        y_item = int(input().strip())
        y.append(y_item)

    result = getTriangleArea(x, y)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: You cannot be using both `python3` and `python2`

Comment: You need to make an attempt at coding the function yourself. Then ask specific questions about any challenges you encounter. This is better googled then asked here.

Comment: https://ncalculators.com/geometry/triangle-area-by-3-points.htm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area of a triangle where `(x1,y1)` is 1st co-ordinate, `(x2,y2)` is 2nd co-ordinate, `(x3,y3)` is 3rd co-ordinate.

```
Area = 1/2[x1(y2 - y3) + x2(y3 - y1) + x3(y1 - y2)]
```

---

```py
x = [2, 3, 7]
y = [4, -6, 8]


def get_area(x, y):
    area = 0.5 * (x[0] * (y[1] - y[2]) + x[1] * (y[2] - y[0]) + x[2]
                  * (y[0] - y[1]))
    return int(area)


coords = zip(x, y)
print('Area of points {}, {}, {} is {}'.format(*coords, get_area(x, y)))
```

---

output

```
Area of points (2, 4), (3, -6), (7, 8) is 27
```

Comment: I have also updated question I want answer in integer format How should i Do that. I cant edit main method of program

Comment: @tyler check the edited answer. But it's better to use decimal as the area will not always be a natural number.

Comment: but I cant pass my testcase Its requirement of my testcase

Comment: `>>> def get_area(x,y):
...     area=0.5*( (x[0]*(y[1]-y[2])) + (x[1]*(y[2]-y[0])) + (x[2]*(y[0]-y[1])) )
...     return int(area)
... 
>>> get_area([1,0,0], [1,1,0])` Gives 0, which is wrong.

Comment: @VladimirVargas `int(area)` would turn float values to integers losing precision. OP stated they only wanted integers as answer. Hence, I put `int(area)` in the answer. Just `return area` to get 0.5 as an answer. [OP's comment about answer being as an interger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597399/area-of-triangle-using-3-sets-of-coordinates/59597516#comment105359867_59597516) and ...[1/2]

Comment: [2/2] ...my [response to it "check the edited answer. But it's better to use decimal as the area will not always be a natural number."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597399/area-of-triangle-using-3-sets-of-coordinates/59597516#comment105359897_59597516) and [previous version of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59597516/3)

Comment: You should put a modulus at the end I think. Otherwise the formula e.g. is not invariant to changing points 1<->2 (it changes sign)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the coordinates of your 3 input points as:

```
x1, y1
x2, y2
x3, y3
```

You can use Pythagorean theorem to find the lengths of all sides:

```
l1 = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)
l2 = sqrt((x2 - x3)**2 + (y2 - y3)**2)
l3 = sqrt((x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2)
```

and then use Heron's Formula for the area of the triangle:

```
p = (l1 + l2 + l3)/2
area = sqrt(p * (p - l1) * (p - l2) * (p - l3))
```